# Find image uri of last saved image in ios phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-3

Can we get image uri of last image that was saved in iphone through phonegap? Remember we are not uploading or capturing image.  Just want to know which was the last image (image uri) saved on the device? Thanks

Comment: Depends on how are you saving the image. Are you asking about the image being loaded in WebView?

Comment: Question is unClear, Can you elaborate it .?

Comment: I am taking screenshot that was saved in device gallery. But I can't get its uri.